# curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh fails on cygwin

Tags: node.js, cygwin, npm

I am unable to install npm on cygwin. I have installed node v0.4.12 which is supposed to be the last supported version of nodejs on cygwin. 
Here is the error I get :

```
curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    85    0    85    0     0    344      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   904
sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
sh: line 1: `<html>Moved: <a href="https://npmjs.org/install.sh">https://npmjs.org/install.sh</a>'
```

Please help me fix this. TIA.

Comment: Btw, Node now supports Windows without needing cygwin. It has since 0.8 with the change from `waf` to `gyp` for their build system. http://nodejs.org/download/ To install any [native addons](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html), you'll want to have [`node-gyp`](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp) and its dependencies installed.

Answer (score 2):

The error is because that URL responds with a 302 redirect. You'll need to use a different URL, which just has a different protocol -- `https` vs. `http`.

```sh
curl https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

Though, as I noted in a comment above, you can install Node 0.8 or later on Windows without cygwin.

Comment: Thanks for those inputs. I tried many things including following (auto) 302 redirects etc.. with both wget and curl (with ssl ignores for bad certs etc..). I finally settled for a crude cygwin copy from a stable laptop env I had setup about a year back for this and it works. Thanks for your thoughts...

Comment: I would like to use cygwin and not ms-dos for this. This can be considered as a constraint :) I really prefer OSx but can't motivate myself to invest personally in one.

Comment: @ZeroGraviti Have you considered trying [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell)? It's not quite terminal or `sh`, but it's much improved over `cmd.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry - late to the game, but this worked for me:

```
curl https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

Comment: It's possible that npmjs.org change their DNS hosting provide and no longer supports "naked domains" (without the www. first)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I thought I'd provide an updated answer that will work as none of the answers will since NPM will return a `301 Redirect` when doing the suggested `curl` calls.

#### Updating NPM on Unix

`curl -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh`

The `-L` option tells `curl` to follow the redirect and adding the `sudo` before the `sh` will ensure that any permission issues are avoided.

#### Updating NPM on Windows

The easiest way to update NPM on Windows is to use the [npm-windows-upgrade](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-windows-upgrade) module. Follow the link for instructions on the actual update procedure.

Answer (score -2):

Now the url is be `https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh`.

So the complete installation command is:

```
curl https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

This might change again in the future. Refer to the [official gist](https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814) for many installation options of node and npm, or [this guide](https://www.joyent.com/blog/installing-node-and-npm/) on joyent blog.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: That's a gist by a Joyent team member and that article on Joyent's blog (https://www.joyent.com/blog/installing-node-and-npm/) links to it, so it's probably going to stay there and be updated more than any peace of code I could put here.